# Why does single pipe character confuse java split method?

Tags: java, parsing

Try the following:

```
String[] = "abcde|12345|xyz".split("|");
```

The results will not be as (at least I..) anticipated.

Using any other character seems to be ok.

```
String[] = "abcde,12345,xyz".split(",");
```

So what is special with the pipe?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Java String.split() expects a RegExp and the pipe character has special meaning in RegExps other than a comma. Try the following:

```
String[] = "abcde|12345|xyz".split("\\|");
```

Comment: figured that one out - but will grant the answer since it includes the solution as well.

Comment: I am sorry moderators for "Thank you" comment but I was struggling for this piece of solution and finally found it here...

Answer (score 7):

The `split` method is expecting a regular expression, and "|" is a special character in regex world: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm

Comment: aha! interesting it is default to use regex. thx.  So.. how does one escape it to do what I want?  Oh wait i got it -- need to escape the backslash .. so as such:  split("\\|")